# Who are these Figures?

Tags: minifigure-identification

[image]

Does anyone recognise the two larger LEGO figures? They are from sets released in the 80’s and I am trying to find out what sets they’re from so I can hopefully build the sets with my son. One is a fireman and came with a fire engine. They fit perfectly between Duplo and LEGO but I can’t seem to find any trace of them, the closest similar product I’ve found is Fabuland which is all animals but the same size figures.

Comment: Based on their apparent size they could be Duplo figures, but I couldn't find any exact matches in Bricklink or Brickset (albeit with an admittedly non-exhaustive search). Are you sure these figures are genuine LEGO pieces? Or they could also be mixed up from multiple separate figures: the legs do look like Fabuland, but the heads don't match.

Comment: @zovits good points, but both Duplo and Fabuland figures were designed to not be taken apart easily.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I know they weren't designed to be separated, that's why I'm sceptical whether they are LEGO figures at all. Nonetheless, "designed to be not taken apart" =/= "can't be taken apart", especially when talking about kids with seemingly unlimited creativity, tenacity and time. But the well-preserved state of the figures indicates the lack of forceful disassembly attempts, so I'm still not sure enough to warrant an answer.

Comment: The sets were identified as Lego Basics 390-1 and 392-2 and I’ve been able to assemble both from my hoard of bricks now that I’ve seen pictures of the vehicles. The figures have Lego stamped inside the legs so I was certain they were original Lego pieces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are [Basic](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=M&catString=155) Figures

- [fab13a  : Basic Figure Human Boy Blue, Black Legs, Brown Hair](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=fab13a#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

  from [390-1: Helicopter](https://brickset.com/sets/390-1/Helicopter)
  [image]

and 
- [fab13c : Basic Figure Human, Black Legs, White Hat](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=fab13c#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

from [392-2: Fire Engine](https://brickset.com/sets/392-2/Fire-Engine)
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I also contacte Lego directly and they identified which sets they came from and after some rummaging I was able to piece the sets together for my young son to play with.